# Cakephp email official example not working?

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I am new to Cakephp (and I have asked a few question on Cakephp here recently) and I am learning by trying out the example on the official site. The following is the link.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html

I added the to my Posts controller which I created before following the official example code.

```
public function emailTesting(){
    $Email = new CakeEmail();
    $Email->config('default');
    $Email->from(array('me@example.com' => 'My Site'));
    $Email->to('myWorkingEmail@gmail.com');
    $Email->subject('Testing Subject');
    $Email->send('Testing email content');
}
```

According to the configuration section,

> It is not required to create app/Config/email.php, CakeEmail can be used without it and use respective methods to set all configurations separately or load an array of configs.

So, I think the above code should work even if I don't create app/Config/email.php. Then,when I try to open the page

```
http://localhost/cakephpTesting/emailTesting/
```

It gives a blank page with no error message (the debug is already 2, which should shows all kind of error message if there is any error) but I didn't receive any email. I also tried different email service provider like Yahoo and my school email. All of them fails, so I think it should be the problem of my code?

So, anybody got any idea on what have I missed?

Comment: Any eror messages in php error log or tmp/logs? Did you create `config/email.php`? How is the `default` config defined?

Comment: I did not create config/email.php, as the official guide says it is not necessary? And default is the default setting of Cakephp, which I don't know what the setting is.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in your question, it is not required to create a app/Config/email.php, IF **you use respective methods to set all configurations separately** or **load an array** of configs.

You are using Email::config() method to load a `$default` config array which is supposed to be defined somewhere. As good practise, it can be defined in the app/Config/email.php or define it in your controller's action (don't recommend the latter). CakeEmail needs to know the transport type, host, port, etc.

Read the [section](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#configuration) after the line that you have mentioned in your question which tells you how to either use the constructor of `CakeEmail` or use the `$config` array.